# Need write permissions to install themes on Linux Mint 17 "Rebecca" Mate

Tags: linux-mint, theme, mate-desktop, read-write

Just installed Linux Mint 17 "Rebecca" Mate. I'm trying to install a new theme and am directed to

http://gnome-look.org/index.php?xcontentmode=167

I've downloaded a couple and their instructions request that contents are copied to

/usr/share/themes

However, I don't have writing permissions to copy to this folder. 
I carried out a workaround to basically force the download into /themes, but encountered a fairly obstructive error upon booting wherein the ICE authority file could not be updated. This has since been resolved.

What's a successful method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply extract that to your home folder into ~/.themes directory? See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E_TyVwRxgfI or http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=90&t=135054 or https://askubuntu.com/questions/121387/how-to-theme-the-cinnamon-desktop which also mention that you can install those .zip files directly via cinnamon control center.

Answer (score -1):

From a command prompt:

```
sudo tar -xzf /path/to/downloaded/file.gz -C /usr/share/themes
```

Comment: It's a .zip unfortunately.

Comment: Use `sudo unzip /path/to/file.zip -d /usr/share/themes`

Comment: Doesn't tar's `-f` need to be the last option before the filename?

Comment: No, the options work in any order. AFAIK

Comment: steeldriver is correct, after -f tar expects the filename.